# Django problem while creating custom user

Tags: python, django

I make my first steps in django. I'm trying to apply my custom User model.

```
class HotelOwner(AbstractUser):
    hasHotel = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

in. Settings:

```
AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'booking.HotelOwner'
```

in Forms:

```
class RegistrationForm(UserCreationForm):

    class Meta:
        model = HotelOwner
        fields = '__all__'
```

in migrations i got this oputput:

```
operations = [
    migrations.CreateModel(
        name='HotelOwner',
        fields=[
            ('id', models.AutoField(auto_created=True, primary_key=True, serialize=False, verbose_name='ID')),
            ('password', models.CharField(max_length=128, verbose_name='password')),
            ('last_login', models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True, verbose_name='last login')),
            ('is_superuser', models.BooleanField(default=False, help_text='Designates that this user has all permissions without explicitly assigning them.', verbose_name='superuser status')),
            ('username', models.CharField(error_messages={'unique': 'A user with that username already exists.'}, help_text='Required. 150 characters or fewer. Letters, digits and @/./+/-/_ only.', max_length=150, unique=True, validators=[django.contrib.auth.validators.UnicodeUsernameValidator()], verbose_name='username')),
            ('first_name', models.CharField(blank=True, max_length=30, verbose_name='first name')),
            ('last_name', models.CharField(blank=True, max_length=150, verbose_name='last name')),
            ('email', models.EmailField(blank=True, max_length=254, verbose_name='email address')),
            ('is_staff', models.BooleanField(default=False, help_text='Designates whether the user can log into this admin site.', verbose_name='staff status')),
            ('is_active', models.BooleanField(default=True, help_text='Designates whether this user should be treated as active. Unselect this instead of deleting accounts.', verbose_name='active')),
            ('date_joined', models.DateTimeField(default=django.utils.timezone.now, verbose_name='date joined')),
            ('hasHotel', models.BooleanField(default=False)),
            ('groups', models.ManyToManyField(blank=True, help_text='The groups this user belongs to. A user will get all permissions granted to each of their groups.', related_name='user_set', related_query_name='user', to='auth.Group', verbose_name='groups')),
            ('user_permissions', models.ManyToManyField(blank=True, help_text='Specific permissions for this user.', related_name='user_set', related_query_name='user', to='auth.Permission', verbose_name='user permissions')),
        ],
        options={
            'verbose_name': 'user',
            'verbose_name_plural': 'users',
            'abstract': False,
        },
        managers=[
            ('objects', django.contrib.auth.models.UserManager()),
        ],
    ),
]
```

RegistrationForm is displayed with all fields, but when I try to log in I got error with every single column, that should be in my HotelOwner model, while it inherits from AbstractUser.

[OperationalError at /booking/login/](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cutsq.png)

Thank you in advance, it's my first post here.

Comment: Did you *run* the migrations? `makemigrations`, is *not* migrating the table, only `migrate` does.

Comment: I got this output: Operations to perform:
  Apply all migrations: admin, auth, booking, contenttypes, sessions
Running migrations:
  No migrations to apply.

Comment: I tried python manage.py migrate booking zero
But got 
django.db.utils.OperationalError: no such table: booking_hotelowner_groups

Comment: Then it looks to me something is wrong withe the dependencies in your migration.

Comment: dependencies = [
        ('auth', '0009_alter_user_last_name_max_length'),
    ]
I got only that dependency.

Comment: Usually when I change the User model I have to completely drop the database, remove all migrations, create new migrations and run these migrations on a fresh database.

Comment: Check applied migrations by running `manage.py showmigrations`. You'll see if it was in fact applied. But in general, you need to create `AbstractUser` model before you run migration for the first time. If you ran it before you created this user model, you'll need to drop the db and rerun migration, as @ThijsKramer said.

Comment: I'm trying to delete a database with various commands, most of them do not work. 
Still have "sqlite3.OperationalError: no such table: booking_hotelowner_groups
" error after running "python manage.py migrate booking zero
"

Comment: admin
 [X] 0001_initial
 [X] 0002_logentry_remove_auto_add
 [X] 0003_logentry_add_action_flag_choices
auth
 [X] 0001_initial
 [X] 0002_alter_permission_name_max_length
 [X] 0003_alter_user_email_max_length
 [X] 0004_alter_user_username_opts
 [X] 0005_alter_user_last_login_null
 [X] 0006_require_contenttypes_0002
 [X] 0007_alter_validators_add_error_messages
 [X] 0008_alter_user_username_max_length
 [X] 0009_alter_user_last_name_max_length
booking
 [X] 0001_initial
contenttypes
 [X] 0001_initial
 [X] 0002_remove_content_type_name
sessions
 [X] 0001_initial

Comment: that's what i recived after calling showmigrations

Comment: Ok guys, deleting db.sqlite3 helped atm.